# How to get position of each element?

Tags: jquery, position, each

I want to detect the position of the cursor above the boxes by making the log background to green, but it only appears on the last one. Look at my example here: https://jsfiddle.net/1ry4dc1j/

How to get log background green for each boxes? Thank you for any help.

```js
$("body").mousemove(function(event) {
  $("log").text("pageX: " + event.pageX + ", pageY: " + event.pageY);

  $("box").each(function() {
    var outerW = $(this).outerWidth();
    var outerH = $(this).outerHeight();
    var offsetL = $(this).offset().left;
    var offsetT = $(this).offset().top;

    var width = outerW + offsetL;
    var height = outerH + offsetT;

    if (event.pageX > offsetL && event.pageX < width && event.pageY > offsetT && event.pageY < height) {
      $("log").addClass("light");
    } else {
      $("log").removeClass("light");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("body").mousemove(function(event) {
 $("log").text("pageX: " + event.pageX + ", pageY: " + event.pageY);
        
});

$( "box" ).hover(
        function() {
            $("log").addClass("light");
        }, function() {
            $("log").removeClass("light");
        }
);
```

```css
html,body{width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}

box {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 20px;
}

log {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 0;
}

log.light
{
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<box></box>
<box></box>
<box></box>


<log></log>
```

Comment: Hmm, but how I can to add it to "drag and drop" function? Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/dsuxamjj/

Comment: Doesn't make sense adding event listener inside mousemove handler. Will add many many listeners

Comment: @charlietfl, I agree.

Comment: @Hvrxld, do you want to add another question to SO for the drag and drop?

Comment: So what are your solutions for "drag and drop" function guys? Any way to add hover to this?

Comment: Drag and drop uses html5 or jqueryui. How did you want drag and drop to work? https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

Comment: @Hvrxld  There are events you can use for that which will likely simplify your issue. Asking in comments is not really appropriate since it has nothing to do with original question which now seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I want to make it in pure jQuery. Thank you for your feedback, really appreciate it.